# Scrolling issues on data.stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, user-interface, data-explorer

I am encountering a couple of scrollbar issues viewing the results table on data.stackexchange.com.  I am using OS X 10.14.6 using both Firefox 108.0.2 and Chrome 108.0.5359.98:

1. This happens *only in Firefox*: The last row is obscured by the scrollbar. I scroll all the way to the bottom but it is still not visible. In Chrome this doesn't happen.
2. In both browsers the table is always slightly wider (one scrollbar's width) than the content area, causing a small amount of horizontal scroll. Resizing the table columns doesn't help.

Both issues are visible in the below screenshot:[image]